# Can't access global variable from query builder function in form type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, query-builder

I am trying to set parameter to query builder in Form type. I want to set `impact` variable to form field query builder. I get `impact` from form options

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title');

    $parentPage = $options["parentPage"];
    $impact = $options["impact"];

    if($parentPage != null){
        $builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
            'class' => "CoreBundle:Page",
            'choices' => array($parentPage)
        ));
    }else{
        $builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
            'class' => "CoreBundle:Page",
            'query_builder' => function(PageRepository $pr){
                $qb = $pr->createQueryBuilder('p');
                $qb->where("p.fullPath NOT LIKE '/deleted%'");

                $qb->andWhere('p.impact = :impact')
                    ->setParameter('impact', $impact); <-'Undefined variable $impact'

                return $qb;
            },
        ));
    }
```

Why this code is shown to be wrong, it says that `$impact` is undefined variable. Isn't it global variable that can be accessed from anywhere in the `buildForm` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you need to explicitly specify variables passed to a closure (aka the query_builder function):

```
    $builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
        'class' => "CoreBundle:Page",
        'query_builder' => function(PageRepository $pr) use ($impact) { // ADD
            $qb = $pr->createQueryBuilder('p');
            $qb->where("p.fullPath NOT LIKE '/deleted%'");

            $qb->andWhere('p.impact = :impact')
                ->setParameter('impact', $impact); <-'Undefined variable $impact'

            return $qb;
        },
    ));
```

Most languages don't need this but php does.
See example 3 : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you arent't passing the parameters into your form builder.
If you `dump($options)` in your `buildForm` function do you see them passed?

To add a custom value into the options your form type should be like;

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Form/Enitiy/PageType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface,
    Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PageType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title');
    // ...
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Page',
            'parentPage' => false,
            'impact' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_page;
    }

}
```

Then your controller action would be something like;

```
$form = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $page, [
            'parentPage' => 'foo',
            'impact' => 'bar'
        ]);
```